# How can I make a list from the string

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

Is there any way to make from string:

```
"I like Python!!!"
```

a list like

```
['I', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', 'P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', '!', '!', '!']
```

Comment: [Please stop adding tags to your question titles.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). The last 4 or so of your questions have had "Python 2.7:" at the beginning of their titles.

Comment: why am i having vote-down?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> mystr = "I like Python!!!"
>>> [c for c in mystr if c != " "]
['I', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', 'P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', '!', '!', '!']
>>> [c for c in mystr if not c.isspace()] # alternately
['I', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', 'P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', '!', '!', '!']
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you don't want any spaces in the resulting list, so try:

```
>>> s = "I like Python!!!"
>>> list(s.replace(' ',''))
['I', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', 'P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', '!', '!', '!']
```

But are you *sure* you need a list here? Bear in mind that in most contexts, strings can be treated just like lists: they are sequences and can be iterated over, and many functions that accept lists also accept strings.

```
>>> for c in ['a','b','c']:
...     print c
... 
a
b
c
>>> for c in 'abc':
...     print c
... 
a
b
c
```

Comment: only correct answer so far

Comment: +1 for saying strings can be used a lot like lists.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
list("I like Python!!!")
```

Output:

```
['I', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', '!', '!', '!']
```

Speed comparison:

```
$ python -m timeit 'list("I like Python!!!")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.783 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit '[x for x in "I like Python!!!"]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 usec per loop
```

Comment: its faster but it doesn't work, it only splits on space delimeters

Comment: So it does, you're right.  Removed that one, added the list comprehension to the speed comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is any better than the others... but comprehensions are fun!

```
[x for x in 'I like Python']
```